# show/hide with CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello
I'm making a mailbox for my website and I want it to show/hide with CSS3 I know there are few tutorial etc on how to do it, but I tried to do it a bit differently. I'm getting a good result, however there is one issue. When I hover on an item the item`:hover` height are not changing together with the text:

**styles.css:**

```
.mailbox_item {
    width: 440px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mailbox_item:hover {
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
}

.mailbox_item_top {
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.mailbox_item_body {
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

**item.php**

```
<div class="mailbox_item">  
    <div class="mailbox_item_top">  
        <h2 class="titleannouncement">Test Announcement</h2>  
        <span class="mail_author">0</span>  
    </div>  
    <div class="mailbox_item_body">  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dapibus lacinia dui at mattis. Donec vitae tellus congue leo egestas tincidunt a eget lorem. Fusce et varius velit. In sollicitudin porta arcu, vel convallis mauris varius ut. Aenean id risus a ante mattis bibendum. Sed mollis ipsum ac metus fringilla eget imperdiet urna laoreet. Quisque tincidunt, purus eu vulputate pulvinar, metus arcu malesuada ante, vitae vehicula ipsum lectus ac libero. Cras in ligula at urna tincidunt tempor. Nam sodales lectus a sem sodales congue. Suspendisse ut ultricies nunc. Aenean blandit tempor ipsum lacinia tincidunt. Mauris ut ipsum non dolor luctus volutpat. Cras quis enim at lacus placerat dictum ut et elit. Vestibulum porta varius dui, rutrum gravida orci semper sit amet. Nam ornare iaculis velit, sit amet euismod felis pulvinar et. Nam sed ipsum eget elit adipiscing tristique.</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="newsdate">  
        <span class="newsdatetext">2011-04-30 06:54:05</span>  
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is what I'm getting:

[Normal state](http://filmuz.com/test.PNG) -  this is as intended

on :hover - the `min-height` value in mailbox_item:hover stays the same and doesn't get higher when the text gets bigger

[on Hover](http://filmuz.com/test1.PNG)

I know that I can use `overflow:hidden;` so the text wont overlap the other window but I wanted to show that there is more text. How can I force the `min-height` value to change if there is more text?

thanks in advance

Comment: The provided HTML does not match the screen shots you have linked. Could you edit the HTML in your question to include the "Contact Us" line as well please?

Comment: If you could post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates/reproduces your problem that'd be appreciated, and useful.

Comment: [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CFEKD/) of the problem as I understand it. Please amend if this is not correct.

Comment: here you go David:http://jsfiddle.net/v4sch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `height:auto` property on the `:hover` rule so that the browser correctly calculates the height when the *menu item* is hovered, overriding the fixed `height:20px` in the `.mailbox_item` rule. See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CFEKD/1/).

Or if you want to use CSS [`text-overflow`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) you could have a *double hover* whereby you show some of the message when hovering on the menu item and then the full message when you hover over the message - see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CFEKD/2/).

You should consider the user experience of having lots of hover events. It is probably distracting to have an *inbox* like list of messages in which the message body shown and hidden when hovering over the message item.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks man :) sometimes the easy stuff is the hardest to figure out ^^ just a question... if I would like to use :active instead of :hover... it would work only when mouse button is pressed... how could I make it to stay?

Comment: I don't really want to go to JS as I'm not that good with JS.

Comment: I don't think using `:active` will work for the reason you already gave. It will stop being _active_ when the mouse button is released. There is nothing in pure CSS that will allow you to do this as far as I know. It will have to be JavaScript. I could make you another demo if you want to go down the JS route. But it's probably best to ask another question since it is really a different problem.

Comment: I would really appreciate that. I checked some scripts but they are not working as I want. I don't know JS so I can't change them to work as I want. the new question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842853/show-hide-div-on-click

Comment: yeah but I have no idea how to implement that to my code.. it works very good in jsFiddle but when I copy/paste the code in between <head></head> .. it does nothing...

Comment: Ah ok. It's because the fiddle includes the jQuery JavaScript library. You will need to either [download it](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) yourself or use [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) to serve your users the necessary library. Basically you need to include something along the lines of `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` or download it and change the `src` to the location of a local copy on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that will be with javascript (jquery will make it easier).

You can also try

```
overflow: auto;
```

If you want a pure css solution that will add a scrollbar when it overflows.