# show/hide div on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello 
I have made a mailbox which uses show/hide on :hover. However someone told me that it could be very distracting to have it like that. I know that it won't work on :active with pure CSS so I would like to ask you guys how can I re-made it while using JS? I'm really bad with JS so I appreciate any help

sample of my mailbox:
http://jsfiddle.net/v4sch/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure you want something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/v4sch/28/

Comment: Man, I should start learning JS :P but it's kinda harder than PHP for me :P

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$('.mailbox_item_top').live('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.mailbox_item_body').toggle();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mailbox_item_body').hide();
});  
</script>
I tried to put it between <head></head> and it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Check here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp . External javascript file is recommended solution

Comment: the issue was that i didn't import jQ libraries... its fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to JavaScript, the easiest method would be to use jQuery UI Accordion.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover

Answer (score 1):

When **page ready** *add an event* to title.
When someone clicks **title** *toogle mailbody*.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").click(function(){
        $("#mailbody").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

[Simple Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/krmby/PMsNv/)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is fixed to having some show/hide effect when mouse is hovered over the element, then how is it distracting? I don't think so. For example, in a blog site when I hover over "reply" button I get an option to reply and this is perfectly nice...

However, hover may perform well when an element is hovered very frequently and hovered transition effect is costly. In this case, you can use timeout() function to make sure the element is hovered for enough time to start processing...

Please specify your requirement more specifically.